# How to set Label or userControl is real transparent

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, transparent

Environment: Visual studio VB or C#

I have some problem about layer of control. My user control has a panel it's set color to be transparent. In main form  I create new instant of user control .But    a panel of user control is not transparent.
Ok,a background of user control  change to same a  background of a main form. 
but when I use Ctrl.bringToFront() 
a panel of user control will cover all of existing control on the form. 
[image]

Below image, I add user control to main form.  MainForm has green panel. all of them is cover by user control.
[image]

I try to use a label control. it has a same problem.
According to third image a label should be blue and red color.

What should i do? if my user control is not rectangle. In my user control,I must use panel for combine many control.it' easy for move or resize.

[image]

Comment: "Transparent" simply means "adopt backcolor of parent" for all controls in NET

Comment: In short, this is not possible in WinForms which is essentially a thin-wrapper around Windows' native USER32/CommonControls and GDI, which does not offer this level of flexibility in user-interface design, for that I would suggest either WPF or HTA... or Windows 8 "Modern". Choose wisely.

Comment: That said, you should avoid large or full-screen graphics in WinForms as they render poorly and with terrible flickering.